# Glossy buttons in wxPython?

Tags: button, coding-style, wxpython

[alt text http://imgkk.com/i/Fmtd8B.jpg](http://imgkk.com/i/Fmtd8B.jpg)

This is how they look in vista. They are glossier than the normal buttons and when the mouse is not over them they are flat. They have a correspondent version on Windows XP. Is there a way to get them using wxPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make a custom button which can look same or better
see my answer to your other question
[Custom Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351448/how-to-make-custom-buttons-in-wx/1361336#1361336)

Answer (score 1):

Get the wxpython docs package from http://www.wxpython.org/download.php
and check out the examples.

Andrea Gavana's agw library, which is included with wxpython now, has a couple of custom widgets called AquaButton and Gradient button both which look very nice. These may work or you may be able to adapt them to suit, they're pure python so you shouldn't have hard time modifying them.