# How to make custom buttons in wx?

Tags: python, button, wxpython

I'd like to make a custom button in wxPython. Where should I start, how should I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a skeleton which you can use to draw totally custom button, its up to your imagination how it looks or behaves

```
class MyButton(wx.PyControl):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, bmp, text, **kwargs):
        wx.PyControl.__init__(self,parent, id, **kwargs)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self._onMouseDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self._onMouseUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self._onMouseLeave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self._onMouseEnter)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND,self._onEraseBackground)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self._onPaint)

        self._mouseIn = self._mouseDown = False

    def _onMouseEnter(self, event):
        self._mouseIn = True

    def _onMouseLeave(self, event):
        self._mouseIn = False

    def _onMouseDown(self, event):
        self._mouseDown = True

    def _onMouseUp(self, event):
        self._mouseDown = False
        self.sendButtonEvent()

    def sendButtonEvent(self):
        event = wx.CommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, self.GetId())
        event.SetInt(0)
        event.SetEventObject(self)
        self.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(event)

    def _onEraseBackground(self,event):
        # reduce flicker
        pass

    def _onPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.SetFont(self.GetFont())
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.GetBackgroundColour()))
        dc.Clear()
        # draw whatever you want to draw
        # draw glossy bitmaps e.g. dc.DrawBitmap
        if self._mouseIn:
            pass# on mouserover may be draw different bitmap
        if self._mouseDown:
            pass # draw different image text
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'll be using it extensively!

Answer (score 5):

When I wanted to learn how to make custom widgets (buttons included) I referenced [Andrea Gavana's page](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls) (full working example there) on the wxPyWiki and Cody Precord's platebutton (the source is in wx.lib.platebtn, also [here](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxPython/trunk/wx/lib/platebtn.py?view=markup) in svn).  Look at both of those and you should be able to build most any custom widget you would like.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the default button class, like this for example:

```
class RedButton(wx.Button):
    def __init__(self, *a, **k):
        wx.Button.__init__(self, *a, **k)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('RED')
        # more customization here
```

Every time you put a `RedButton` into your layout, it should appear red (haven't tested it though).

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [Generic Button](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.buttons-module.html) or a [Bitmap Button](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.BitmapButton-class.html).