# Buttons on a gradient bar to access different panels

Tags: python, button, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

The following code makes a window with a **grey gradient bar**.

[image]

```
import wx

class GradientFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, lambda event: None)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()

    def OnSize(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        self.Refresh()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        rect = self.GetClientRect()
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush("white"))
        dc.Clear() 
        rect.SetHeight(30)
        dc.GradientFillLinear(rect, '#fbfbfb', '#efefef', wx.SOUTH)
        rect.SetTop(30)
        rect.SetHeight(2)
        dc.GradientFillLinear(rect, '#dbdbdb', '#c1c1c1', wx.SOUTH)

app = wx.App(0)
frame = GradientFrame(None, 'Test')
app.MainLoop()
```

I would like to add toogle buttons like the following screenshot, that allows to access to different **pages** / **panels** of the GUI (each of them containing their own widgets, etc.)

[image]

**What is the good framework for that** : should these buttons be created manually in `OnPaint` (this would be very 'low-level') or somewhere else? Is there a ready-to-use way to use buttons linked to different **pages** ?

Comment: FlatNotebook with tab style set as Ribbon style seems similar to your screenshot & requirements

Comment: @Yoriz I tried FlatNotebook, but I don't find the same layout... Which option did you choose in FlatNotebook ?

Comment: Open up the demo and go to the Tab Appearance menu. Then "Tabs Style" and the Ribbon one is at the bottom. Definitely a good option, although I don't think you can tell the tabs to be centered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good framework for creating custom widgets. However, there are some good recipes out there:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351448/how-to-make-custom-buttons-in-wx
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls

Those two links should get you started. You can also take a look at the source for GenericButtons, AquaButton or PlateButton for additional ideas.

Alternatively, you could also just create a panel that's a specific size and put some of the custom buttons or just regular buttons on it instead.

Here's an example of how to use PlateButtons that should get you started:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.platebtn as platebtn

class GradientFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, lambda event: None)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

        # add plate buttons
        top_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btn_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        labels = ["Morceaux", "Albums", "Artistes", "Genres"]
        style = platebtn.PB_STYLE_GRADIENT
        for label in labels:
            btn = platebtn.PlateButton(self.panel, label=label, style=style)
            btn.SetPressColor(wx.Colour(208,208,208))
            btn_sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.RIGHT|wx.LEFT|wx.CENTER, 5)

        top_sizer.Add(btn_sizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        top_sizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(top_sizer)

        self.Center()
        self.Show()

    def OnSize(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        self.Refresh()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self.panel)
        rect = self.panel.GetClientRect()
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush("white"))
        dc.Clear() 
        rect.SetHeight(30)
        dc.GradientFillLinear(rect, '#fbfbfb', '#efefef', wx.SOUTH)
        rect.SetTop(30)
        rect.SetHeight(2)
        dc.GradientFillLinear(rect, '#dbdbdb', '#c1c1c1', wx.SOUTH)

app = wx.App(0)
frame = GradientFrame(None, 'Test')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks @MikeDriscoll for your answer.
Indeed, `PlateButton` seems to be what I'm looking for https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/demo/PlateButton.py...

(I just want to put these buttons in the center of the bar, and in the previous code, I am lost with all the `wx.BoxSizer` etc.)
Unfortunately, I'm still lost in this code...

Do you think I could offer a bounty if someone can help me on implementing this?

Comment: Also take a look at ButtonPanel , a custom panel with gradient background.

Comment: Hi @MikeDriscoll, thanks so much for the code. A small thing : there is no gradient in the button itself, do you have an idea to restore this gradient ?   And the last one : how is it possible to change the default Blue of `PlateButton` into a grey ?

Comment: I added `style=style` in the call of `PlateButton`, but still the gradient is not enabled when button is disabled.

Comment: Just add the style back in...I fixed the code so it did. To change the highlight color, you have to call SetPressColor, which is kind of counter-intuitive. Also see the demo for examples of other options.

Comment: I'm not sure the gradient can be enabled when the button is disabled. You would have to ask on the wxPython google group about that. The author of PlateButton hangs out there, so he will probably respond.

Comment: About gradient, @MikeDriscoll, in `PlateButtonDemo.py` (from wxPython's demo ) there is the 2nd pannel (called `Gradient background`) for which the buttons have a gradient background. It is precisely the thing I cannot make work!

Comment: This looks like you need to add style flag "PB_STYLE_NOBG" to me.

Comment: Waw, thanks again @MikeDriscoll. The last thing I need to modify is : no change when hover, the color should change *only* when button is pressed.